# magento table "sales_flat_order" field "protect_code" explanation

Tags: mysql, database, magento

We are working on magento database and tables. Magento seems to write a code in table `sales_flat_order` field `protect_code` to define if there is a invoice or a shipment done already. It would look something like

`01b335` or
`a0a243`

But there is no `key` to understand what this protection code means. Is there an explanation of the meaning of these codes and how they are generated?

Answer (score 28):

### Where is it generated?

If you look in `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` on around line `2052`, you will find the following:

```
$this->setData('protect_code', substr(md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true) . ':' . microtime(true)), 5, 6));
```

This is where `protect_code` is generated for the order (using a combination of md5, uniqid, and random integer.

### What is it used for?

If you look in `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Helper/Guest.php` and find the `loadValidOrder` function. You will see `protect_code` used in some areas to ensure the order being loaded is the correct one for the guest's cookie value.

It's also used in other areas, such as tracking information comparisons.  You can see several instances of the `getProtectCode()` method being called in the Shipment models to compare the order to the tracking information.  An example of a function that uses it is:

```
public function getTrackingInfoByTrackId()
{
    $track = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')->load($this->getTrackId());
    if ($track->getId() && $this->getProtectCode() == $track->getProtectCode()) {
        $this->_trackingInfo = array(array($track->getNumberDetail()));
    }
    return $this->_trackingInfo;
}
```

As you can see with `$this->getProtectCode() == $track->getProtectCode()`, the tracking `protect_code` must match the Shipment `protect_code`.