# Understanding magento sales_flat_order table

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to understand the use of different columns present in magento sales_flat_order table..
this is what i have got so far...

---

### protect_code

used to ensure the order being loaded is the correct one for the guest's cookie value, but not sure why magento sets this field for even logged in users..
[magento table "sales_flat_order" field "protect_code" explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986295/magento-table-sales-flat-order-field-protect-code-explanation)

---

### Cancelled, Invoice, Refunded ...

- discount_canceled, discount_invoiced, discount_refunded
- shipping_amount, shipping_canceled, shipping_invoiced, shipping_refunded
- shipping_tax_amount, shipping_tax_refunded
- subtotal_canceled.....
- tax_amount.....
- total_canceled....

then again repeated for base_discount_canceled...

I already know everything with base has to do with base currency and the other is to with store currency..

**Not able to understand need of so many columns**  **discount_canceled, discount_invoiced, discount_refunded**
Magento can issue partial refunds, so can understand for refunded..

but for invoice, canceled it can rather have only one field 
`eg. invoice = true and use grandtotal, basegrandtotal fields ..`

if this was a design issue than why this is present even in magento 2?
If i am missing some feature of magento which requires this, then i am more than interested to know about it ..

---

### edit_increment

- edit_increment
- relation_child_id, relation_child_real_id, relation_parent_id, relation_parent_real_id

I found this in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Sales/Order/Create.php

```
public function createOrder()
..
..

        $oldOrder = $this->getSession()->getOrder();
        $originalId = $oldOrder->getOriginalIncrementId();
        if (!$originalId) {
            $originalId = $oldOrder->getIncrementId();
        }
        $orderData = array(
            'original_increment_id'     => $originalId,
            'relation_parent_id'        => $oldOrder->getId(),
            'relation_parent_real_id'   => $oldOrder->getIncrementId(),
            'edit_increment'            => $oldOrder->getEditIncrement()+1,
            'increment_id'              => $originalId.'-'.($oldOrder->getEditIncrement()+1)
        );

..
..
        $this->getSession()->getOrder()->setRelationChildId($order->getId());
        $this->getSession()->getOrder()->setRelationChildRealId($order->getIncrementId());
```

But i am not sure , for what condition this code is executed

Some old orders in the database are having edit_increment as 1....

Few other fields..

> adjustment_negative , adjustment_positive , ext_customer_id , ext_order_id

P.S- Using magento enterprise..

Comment: An order can also be partially invoiced if partially refunded. Makes total sense, you just invoice the not refunded part.

Comment: For edit_increment, magento cannot edit an order, or at least save it on the same order when edited. For some obvious reasons. The edit_increment will then be suffixed to the increment_id when you edit an order for example 100000052-1

Comment: For the rest there is 201 columns in sales_flat_order (on my 1.9.22), so I think the question is really too wide for a format like stack overflow

Comment: yes i do understand, 201 columns are a lot... thats the reason i have pointed out specific columns in the question , asking only about field mentioned in the ques

Comment: @b.enoit.be got the use edit_increment, thanks for ur inputs ..